# Xcode Preview crashes because of RealmSwift model changes

Tags: ios, swiftui, realm, xcode12, mongodb-realm

I am developing an app with SWIFTUI, RealmSwift and Xcode 12.4
Along with development, Realm data model changes, eg. some values are removed, some are added...

When I make changes on the data model, I simply delete my app on my device and re-install it to avoid crash derived from Realm migration issue.
Now the problem is, Xcode Preview crashes because of the same migration issue and I have no idea how to do a fresh re-build for the Xcode Preview.

Below is the DiagnosticReports Xcode gave me.

> Migration is required due to the following errors:
>
> - Property 'A' has been removed.
> - Property 'B' has been added.

Realm migration for a Preview? It doesn't make sense!

I tried cleaning build, deleting derived data, reboot... without luck.
There should be some way to handle Realm model changes for Preview provider.

Please somebody guide me what should I do to get my Preview back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I soloved my problem based on [this forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/661669).

I got my XCode Preview back.

Seems like Core Data has similar sort of issue of mine.

> To start from a fresh slate you can use the terminal app and run *xcrun
> simctl --set previews delete all*

Comment: Thanks for this! This problem haunted me for days.

Comment: Hey, this solution works fine for me. but after some builds, it keeps coming back because schema will be set to 0 again! any solution for this? `Provided schema version 0 is less than last set version 27.`

Comment: Thanks for your answer this solved the problem. But. anyway I didn't found where is the Realm.default database file stored on the preview simulator.